# Android translation lint check - how to disable when only two out of 3 translations is required?

Tags: android, android-lint

I have an app that usually translates into 3 different languages. Thai, indonesia and english (default). but on occasion i have a feature that is only applicable to thailand and english and indonesia does not need translations so i have left indonesia local string file empty.

Lets take a look at an example using android studios strings translations editor:

[image]

as you can see these a1,a2,a3,a4 are only required in thailand and english (default). so i left indonesia empty.  Now lint gives off warnings that i am missing translations for indonesia.  Is there any flag i can use to stop the lint check or is the best practice to still copy the string into indonesia even though its not used ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to specify what you want exactly since your use case is I guess not widely used and it didn't make it into lint.

You can however use the `tools:ignore="MissingTranslation"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <string name="foo" tools:ignore="MissingTranslation">1</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: do you know if  tools:ignore="MissingTranslation" can be added to the resource tag so lint ignores the entire file ?

Comment: I think so. Just try it out.